# typeof 'enum' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassType<unknown>'

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

i wanna create abstract generic order class like following

```
export function Order<T>(OrderItem: ClassType<T>) {
    @InputType({ isAbstract: true})
    abstract class Order implements IOrder<OrderItem>{
        @Field(type => OrderItem)
        field: OrderItem;

        @Field(type => OrderByDirection)
        direction: OrderByDirection;
    }

}
```

I create an order item from enum

```
export enum BaseOrderItem {
    CREATED_AT = "createdAt",
}
```

and when i put enum to T, I got TS2345,

type of BaseOrderItem is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassType'

```
@InputType()
export class TestOrder extends Order(BaseOrderItem) {}
```

how can i use enum to inputtype dynamically??

And when i lift 'ClassType' restrictions

```
export function Order<T>(OrderItem) {
    @InputType({ isAbstract: true })
    abstract class Order implements IOrder<T> {
        @Field(type => OrderItem)
        field: T;

        @Field(type => OrderByDirection, { nullable : true})
        direction: OrderByDirection;
    }
}
```

i got message

```
type 'void' is not a constructor function type
```

Answer (score 0):

Just lift the `ClassType` restrictions if you want to use enums.

The same would probably go to `IOrder<OrderItem>`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. when i lift the ClassType restrictions i got an message like following.

Type 'void' is not a constructor function type

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this question from google. I was able to solve it with the following:

```
export function Order<T>(OrderItem: object) {
    @InputType({ isAbstract: true})
    abstract class Order implements IOrder<T>{
        @Field(type => OrderItem)
        field: T;

        @Field(type => OrderByDirection)
        direction: OrderByDirection;
    }
    return Order;
}
```

Note: the `isAbstract` property has to be removed if using version >2.0.0 of type-graphql.